# write envoy filter using wasm langu

Tags: javascript, security, istio, webassembly, envoyproxy

we need to create an envoy filter using wasm, there is few language that supporting it.

- assamblyscript (js)
- tiny-go
- rust
- c++

we need to do some auth processing/header modification, serialisations / deserialisations  etc, my question is which language has the most supporting libs for wasm ?

the reason that Im asking that is that I start with `tiny-go` and found that many feature/libs of go is missing which make the dev very difficult...